# Plotting the results of linear regression model using ggplot2 - interpretation

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, lm, interpretation

I have only recently learnt how to undertake a regression analysis in R. I was wondering whether someone could help me in interpreting what my ggplot result shows below?

[image: GGplot for my linear model]

Comment: What exactly is your question? What information do you want to gather from the plot? Please formulate your question more specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Your plot is showing a linear model based on House prices as a function of recorded crimes. The model is plotted is the blue line. You can see that there is a negative effect of house prices as crimes increases. As someone else has mentioned the grey areas around the line represent your 95% confidence intervals of the model. If you want to get the full output of the model and be able to see the actual intercept and slope I would recommend creating the model in R and looking at it's summary. Something like this:

```
model<-lm(HousePrices~Recordedcrime)
summary(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you show your code here because the code could tell a lot of things? For example, ggplot automatically helps you to plot a linear regression line based on least square method, and by default gives you a 95% confidence interval of the model. You could go to the ggplot examples that shows how to interpret them, learn from examples.

Also, if you want to perform regression, you could use the r command lm, or glm (the two most elementary) and will get output.

Answer (score 0):

Your plot only shows the data with the adjusted regression line over it. It doesn't tell you much about the parameters, for example. It is only a way to `show` the regression line.

Comment: The one thing to add is that they grey area is the 95 % confidence interval.  Exact information is easy to find via google.